# How to go back to the beginning of a code?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to make this calculator and I want it to go back to the beginning of the code after the end so the user could do as many calculations as they want but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've been trying while loops but they don't seem to work.

This is what I have so far.

```
def main():

   def add(x, y):
      return x + y

   def subtract(x, y):
      return x - y

   def multiply(x, y):
      return x * y

   def divide(x, y):
      return x / y

   def mod


print ('Hello! I am your personal calculator. Please enter the operation you would like to use.')

print ('Your choices are, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division!')

x = input('What is your choice?')

num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number"))

num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number"))

if x== 'addition':
   print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))

elif x== 'subtraction':
   print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif x== 'multiplication':
   print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif  x== 'division':
   print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

else:
   print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: this is not valid python code... could you please strip it down to a **minimal** version that reproduces your problem (i.e. a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Answer (score 1):

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

def continue_cal():
    resp = input("Continue ? Y/N ")
    if resp == "n" or resp == "N":
        return False
    return True

print('Hello! I am your personal calculator. Please enter the operation you would like to use.')

while True:

    print('Your choices are, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division!')

    x = input('What is your choice?')

    num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number"))

    num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number"))

    if x == 'addition':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

    elif x == 'subtraction':
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

    elif x == 'multiplication':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

    elif x == 'division':
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))

    else:
        print("Invalid Input")

    if not continue_cal():
       break
```

output:

```
Hello! I am your personal calculator. Please enter the operation you would like to use.

Your choices are, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division!
What is your choice?addition

Please enter your first number5

Please enter your second number15

5 + 15 = 20

Continue ? Y/N
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be the following, however now user will have to specify when to exit by inputting `exit` as an input choice.

```
while (True):
    print ('Hello! I am your personal calculator. Please enter the operation you would like to use.')

    print ('Your choices are, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division!')

    x = input('What is your choice?')

    num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number"))

    num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number"))

    if x== 'addition':
       print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))

    elif x== 'subtraction':
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

    elif x== 'multiplication':
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

    elif  x== 'division':
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
    elif x== 'exit':
        break
    else:
       print("Invalid Input")
```